# Can we use NgRx Data with pagination style REST API response?

Tags: ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I am currently using NgRx Data to perform CRUD operation on couple of entities on my project. Now, I've to develop pagination. Hence, REST API response is going to be like:

```js
{
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "total": 100,
    "total_page": 10,
    "data": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

AFAIK, NgRx Data works well with entities, I've no clue how to deal with this. Could you please redirect me to some light? Thank you.

Comment: Could you expand a little on your requirements, are you looking to create paginated table / happy to have repeated api calls / able to work with websockets? For project I'm working on I'm using a `getWithQuery` (e.g. /api/?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&sortOrder=asc) and implementing a `DefaultDataService` to map the api result so that the `data` entities get saved to the entityCache.

Comment: @AndrewAllen I ended up doing exactly same as you mentioned. Just wondering how do you determine if there is a next page? What is your response look like? Can you share an example if you don't mind?

Comment: I had a similar requirement, but with Django REST as the backend. The responses from differ a little, but there are similarities. To support this I created custom versions of DefaultDataService and DefaultDataServiceFactory and registered them with Angular via providers. I have captured it in a post [here](https://www.smallpearl.com/blog/paginated-responses-in-ngrxdata/). Putting it here so that it could help someone who lands here from google search.

Answer (score -1):

Even I was facing a similar issue. So for people who are new to NgRx data, I have created an *EntityDataListInterface* which was similar to:

```
{
    page: number,
    per_page: number,
    total: number,
    total_page: number,
    data: EntityDataItem[]
}
```

For each section I am working on I create a different service. Lets call it *ComponentService*. Inside this *ComponentService* I access the EntityService(which implements ***EntityCollectionServiceBase***<***EntityDataItem***>) and entity's DataService (which implements ***DefaultDataService***<***EntityDataListInterface***>).

Once the API returns *EntityDataListInterface* data, you can use *addManyToCache* to add them into the entity cache.

Inside the module, register the *EntityDataItem* by passing the ***filterFn***. Now you can call *setFilter* to filter the entities based on indexes(or any pagination logic like shown below) and the result would be accessible via *filteredEntities$*.

```
//eds: EntityDefinitionService in the constructor

const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
      EntityDataItem: {
        filterFn:(entities: EntityDataItem[], pattern:{startIndex: number, endIndex: number}) => {
          return entities.filter((entity, index) => {
            return ((index >= pattern.startIndex) && (index <= pattern.endIndex));
          })
        }
      }
    };
eds.registerMetadataMap(entityMetadata);
```

Subscribe to *filteredEntities$* in your component and it will solve the pagination issue.